# Search for *.dll but only output those of a specific version using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have this script in Powershell:

```
$100DLLPath = (Get-ChildItem -Path c:\ -Recurse -erroraction 'silentlycontinue' -Include *100.dll)
$VersionInfo100 = (Get-ChildItem $100DLLPath).VersionInfo
Write-Host $VersionInfoATL100 | FT
```

Now this will display the properties of any *.100.dll.  What I want to do is search for those same DLLs but only display those that meet a certain fileversion.

Answer (score 0):

```
$100DLLPath = (Get-ChildItem -Path c:\ -Recurse -erroraction 'silentlycontinue' -Include *100.dll)
foreach ($dll in $100DLLPath) {
    if ($dll.VersionInfo -match '1\.2\.3\.4') {
        ## emit file info
        $dll.VersionInfo
    }
}
```

Comment: `-match` uses regex, so you need to escape the dots. Also, `VersionInfo` is an object with lots of properties, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

To compare versions, it is best to use them not as strings, but as [System.Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version) objects.

Something like this:

```
# the version you want to comare against
[version]$version = '2000.1.2.3'          # Major.Minor.Build.Revision

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Filter '*100.dll' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    Where-Object { $_.VersionInfo.FileVersionRaw -ge $version } |   # or any other comparison operator
    ForEach-Object { $_.VersionInfo } | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

<sup>Instead of `FileVersionRaw`, you may also want to do this against the `ProductVersionRaw` property. Both are [version] objects.</sup>